# Symfony 3. Связь таблиц many-to-one

Tags: mysql, symfony2, symfony3

Делал выборку данных

```
$qb =  $this->createQueryBuilder('sa');
    $result = $qb->select('sa.kpi, r')
        ->where('sa.year =:year')
        ->andWhere('sa.week =:week')
        ->andWhere('sa.branch IS NULL')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Region', 'r', 'WITH','r.id = sa.region')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'year' => $year,
            'week' => $week,
        ))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

для leftjoin сделал связь многие-к-одному

```
manyToOne:
    region:
        targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Region
        joinColumn:
            name: region
            referencedColumnName: id
```

выборка работает, сейчас пришлось записать данные в таблицу

```
                    $sa = new SA();
                    $sa->setDate(new \DateTime("now"));
                    $sa->setYear($this->year);
                    $sa->setWeek($this->week);
                    $sa->setRegion($region_value['id']);
                    $sa->setBranch($branch_value['id']);
                    $sa->setCity($city_value['id']);
                    $sa->setKpi($kpi);
                    $em->persist($sa);
                    $em->flush();
```

и теперь ругается на строку $sa->setRegion($region_value['id']);

Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\Region" for association field "SABundle\Entity\SA#$region", got "string" instead.

Я так понимаю, что вместо значения id нужно в setRegion передать объект AppBundle\Entity\Region, но что-то не понимаю как.

Answer (score 1):

Сам и отвечу

```
$r = $repoRegion->find($region_value['id']);
$sa->setRegion($r);
$b = $repoBranch->find($branch_value['id']);
$sa->setBranch($b);
$c = $repoCity->find($city_value['id']);
$sa->setCity($c);
```